# How to get video bytes from react-video-recorder

Tags: reactjs, react-native, video

I'm saving the video bytes from react-video-recorder, however, the video isn't a valid webm video file. Here is a piece of my code:

const onVideoChange = (video) => {
video.arrayBuffer().then((arrayBuffer) => {
dispatch(
submitVideo(
[
{
name: "video.webm",
bytes: new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer),
},
],
submitVideoCallback
)
);
});
};

on renders:
VideoRecorder onRecordingComplete={onVideoChange}

When I receive the video bytes on the back-end and save the video file like video.webm, VLC isn't able to play it.

What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks
Sergio Stateri Junior.

Comment: Give link to a small test file so we can check it.